# Identify this movie: the protagonists are searching for what is beyond by reaching clinical death and coming back

Tags: identify-this-movie, mystery

I saw this movie 10-15 years ago and can't really remember the details. What I remember is that the protagonists developed some way to achieve temporary clinical death. They are basically trying to find out what is on the other side.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Could it be [Flatliners](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099582/), a 1990 movie starring Kiefer Sutherland, Julia Roberts and Kevin Bacon?

It is about medical students doing exactly what you describe.